# How to read data written in binary format in decimal format with Python?

Tags: python, binary, format

I need help with reading the data for my project. Data which I am trying to read are written in binary format, using FORTRAN in the following way:

It is in fortran binary format with "toto" an array of single float

```
  open(unit=11,file=outfich,form='unformatted')
  write(11)ngal,9 ! Number of galaxies for which ages are computed

  allocate(toto(ngal,9))
  toto(1:ngal,1)=float(galid_tab(1:ngal))
  toto(1:ngal,2)=sfrgal10_tab (1:ngal)
  toto(1:ngal,3)=sfrgal100_tab (1:ngal)
  toto(1:ngal,4)=sfrgal1000_tab(1:ngal)
  toto(1:ngal,5)=agegal_tab(1:ngal)
  toto(1:ngal,6)=mgal_tab(1:ngal)*1d11
  toto(1:ngal,7)=xgal_tab(1:ngal)*3.08d24/unit_l+0.5d0
  toto(1:ngal,8)=ygal_tab(1:ngal)*3.08d24/unit_l+0.5d0
  toto(1:ngal,9)=zgal_tab(1:ngal)*3.08d24/unit_l+0.5d0
  write(11)toto
```

I was trying to read the data using:

```
dt = np.dtype([('galid', float), ('sfrgal10', float), ('sfrgal100', float),('sfrgal1000', float), ('agegal', float), ('mgal', float), ('xgal', float), ('ygal', float), ('zgal', float)])
numpy.fromfile(filepath, dtype=dt, count=-1, sep='')
```

but the values I get don't really make any sense. The values I am supposed to get are:

```
galid ~ 1-120000
mgal ~ 0-2
xgal, ygal, zgal ~ -50 - +50
```

I also tried using `np.float16` and `'<f8'` instead of float, the values are different, but still don't make much sense.

I also tried using:

```
with open(filepath, mode='rb') as file: # b is important -> binary
    fileContent = file.read()
    data = struct.unpack("fffffffff", fileContent[:36])
print(data)
```

Comment: Perhaps you could add a link to an example binary file?

Comment: The binary data that I read is nonsense. This is what I read when I use FORTRAN: (one line)                    1           1   11.695393       10.137738       7.8165536       10.151393       4.3594775       44.899860      -13.991988       42.087212                              So, there is another variable in the beginning, which is just a number (1,2,3,4...). But even when I add that to my code in python (('i', 'f4')), it still doesn't work

Comment: Without seeing an example file, it will be difficult to help you. You can use a service such as [filebin](https://filebin.ca/) to upload a file to and then post a link to the upload here. That way we could see it.

Comment: Search for a description of the FORTRAN float format and read your data in binary mode.

Comment: https://filebin.ca/3LQx5LCn7YRU/sfr.dat